# how to check against parsing error when download apk file to sdcard

Tags: android, download, apk

When there is a version update I am getting the apk file from server this apk file sometimes there is a corrupt download. This causes parsing error when I try to install the file is there any way to make sure file is apk file not corrupt before running it.

I check for 
`( (apkFile!=null) && (apkFile.exists()) )` and the size but there are still exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Since you are being made aware that there is a new file, in that notice include a md5 of the apk file. After downloading get the md5 of the downloaded apk and compare to the expected. If they are different then you had a corrupted download.